# Two-sample $t$-test vs Tukey's method

Tags: anova, t-test, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

Even if the $F$ statistic in an ANOVA test is significant, we may need to do further testing before drawing conclusions. The most common method for doing this involves the use of a multiple comparisons procedure. I am trying to understand why Tukey's method is used over the two-sample $t$-test. I read the following below which suggested that doing all the pairwise tests (presumably it means two-sample $t$-tests) can lead to false positives (Type I errors). Why should this happen conceptually?

> Tukey's procedure allows us to conduct separate tests to decide
>   whether $\mu_i = \mu_j$ for each pair of means in an ANOVA study of
>   $k$ population means. Like all multiple comparison procedures, Tukey's
>   method is based on the selection of a "family" significance leve,
>   $\alpha$, that applies to the entire collection of pairwise hypothesis
>   tests. For example, when using the Tukey procedure with a significance
>   level of, say, 5%, we are assured that there is at most a 5% chance of
>   obtaining a false positive among the entire set of pairwise tests,
>   That is, there is at most a 5% chance of mistakenly concluding that
>   two population means differ when, in fact, they are equal. This is
>   very different from simply conducting all the pairwise tests as
>   individual tests, each at $\alpha=0.05$, which can result in a high
>   probability of finding false positives among the pairwise tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply that if (under the null hypothesis of no effects) there's a 5% chance, say, of a false positive in *each one* of 20 tests, say; there's a greater than 5% chance of a false positive in *any one* of those 20 tests.  If the tests are independent, the change of getting a false positive in *none* is $95\%^{20}=35.8\%$, and so the chance of a false positive in *at least one* is $64.2\%$—this is the family-wise error that multiple comparisons tests control. Of course pairwise comparisons of all means after ANOVA are not independent, and Tukey's test takes this into account.